# Static IP is not working outside my network

Tags: router

I have a static IP and i am using it for a web application through port forwarding. It was working perfect and suddenly it stopped working in outside of my network. I can able to able to access it if connected to my network through WIFI or LAN. But If I use other networks I can't able to access it. I tried resetting and re-configuring the router still the issue exist. My firewall is in off mode. Please help me to solve this.

One more thing is internet is not working if I set IP4 address to obtain from network but I set IP manually on IP4 it works fine.

I am using Huawei HG532s router.

```
IP4 192.168.1.250
Subnet mask 255.255.255.0
Default Gateway 192.168.1.1
Preferred DNS 192.168.1.1
Alternate DNS 80.87.78.11
```

I have static IP `41.xx.xxx.xxx`
and my application path `41.xx.xxx.xxx:1000/index.php`

Comment: What OS are you using? Reset the network adapter settings back to auto. Flush the DNS cache. From outside your network you can use NMAP or similar. If you are troubleshooting from home use canyouseeme.org or similar.

Comment: it works if I change new router.